# Codename One IntelliJ: Sending build doies nothing suddenly

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build my App but when sending the build nothing really happens and it won't show up on the build server as well. I have built it several times before, I don't know whats wrong. He executes some tasks and then says finished but does not tell me anymore to check build server or anything which he did before. The same is happening when i select iOS build, successfull but nothing more appens.

Can you tell me whats wrong?

Edit for Shai:

Probleme here is that the terminal is saying nothing at all, before and after trying to build it' still

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

F:\Users\Maxl\IdeaProjects\GehmaLiveApp>" and nothing more.
```

When build it in device Simulator its output is:

```
F:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java" -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=F:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "F:/Users/Maxl/IdeaProjects/GehmaLiveApp\out\production\GehmaLiveApp;F:/Users/Maxl/IdeaProjects/GehmaLiveApp\src;F:/Users/Maxl/IdeaProjects/GehmaLiveApp\lib\CodenameOne.jar;F:/Users/Maxl/IdeaProjects/GehmaLiveApp\JavaSE.jar;native/internal_tmp;lib/impl/cls;F:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar"com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.rosscode.gehma.main
    Nov 19, 2016 12:28:04 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
    WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5. 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

and then everything starts correctly. However, neither Android build nor iOs buil does anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you reloaded the build server page and still it doesn't show take a look at the console output which usually says exactly what went wrong. By default IntelliJ hides the output behind a tree like structure but if you turn it off with the button on the left you can see the actual text.

It's probable that you exceeded one of the free quotas (in size or build credits), if none of these resolves your issue use the online support chat in the website on the bottom right to resolve the issue be sure to provide the full text output of the build sent so our support engineer can help with that.

Comment: Please see my edit. I guess I will contact your support.